# Subscription out of range error in Random Items

Tags: vba, excel

My code is supposed to take items from list box and separates them in order to establish it in a table on a sheet. The weird part is not that it keeps throwing

> Subscription out of Range

It is that it throws it for random specific items and I tried using different items that have similar characteristics and yet they work. All these items come from the same sheet. I was hoping for somebody to look at my code to make sure that it is my code and it's not some characteristic in the word that I missed

Here is where the error occurs:

```
.Range("A" & (i + 1)).Value = strsplt(i)
```

This is the whole code:

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, ii As Long
Dim found As Boolean
Dim str As String

Dim message, title, defaultval As String
Dim quantity As String

Dim strsplt() As String
ReDim strsplt(0 To i)

'Seperate Items and put them in table with quantity needed

With Me.selecteditems
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(9).Range("A:B").ClearContents
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            found = True
            For ii = 0 To .ColumnCount - 1
                If str = "" Then
                    str = .List(i, ii) & vbTab
                Else
                    If ii < .ColumnCount - 1 Then
                        str = str & .List(i, ii) & vbTab
                    Else
                        str = str & .List(i, ii)
                    End If
                End If
            Next ii
            message = "How much" & vbCrLf & str & "?"
            title = "Amount"
            defaultval = "1"
            quantity = InputBox(message, title, defaultval)
            strsplt() = Split(str, "             ")
        End If
        'On Error Resume Next
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(9)
                .Range("A" & (i + 1)).Value = strsplt(i)
                .Range("B" & (i + 1)).Value = quantity
        End With
        'On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: `ReDim strsplt(0 To i)` doesn't throw an error? You don't define `i` but `ReDim` to it. You may need to edit/move that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ReDim strsplt(0 To i)
> ```

When that instruction runs, the value of `i` is `0`; the `ReDim` statement is effectively useless/redundant.

Then you assign the array:

> ```
> strsplt() = Split(str, "             ")
> ```

The parentheses are redundant, but that's not the problem: the problem is that if `str` can't be `Split` into `i` elements using that `"             "` delimiter, then this:

> ```
> .Range("A" & (i + 1)).Value = strsplt(i)
> ```

Is pulling an out-of-bounds value from the array.

I'd love to help streamline your code, but the logic is rather convoluted and I can't spend an hour on this. Learn to place breakpoints (F9), step through your code (F8) and inspect local variable values (using the *Locals* toolwindow, or with `?`/`Print` statements in the *immediate* pane, or just by hovering the variables in break mode), and you should quickly find a solution.

Comment: That helped because after reading your thing I realized it was the space, but now I realized that some of my things are not spacing out properly, do you maybe have advice on that?

Comment: Without knowing what "spacing out properly" means, I'm afraid not

Comment: When I was trying to separate it, I realized that some of them have 11 spaces ,resulting in me putting , `"           "`, as the delimiter. When you helped me, I understood that the space ^ was the problem. So when I put it in again it resulted with me finding out some of the items are spaced by 1

Comment: You might want to look into what regular expressions can do for you. You can use them to split on *any number of spaces*, and have a much more reliable solution.

Comment: I was wondering whether you knew what I should ass or edit. Also, a part of this code was helped by another user, so I don't know how some of it works